test if a curve is above another
I have defined 2 curves.
The definition is more complex than showed. This is only to be easily reproductible
c1: y= 2
c2: y=x+1 

I now want a curve c3 so that y=1 if c1 if above c2 and y=2 if c2 is above c1.
I wrote c3: y=If(y(c1)>y(c2),1,2)
No errors are raised by geogebra but it only print a line defined like this y=2.
Why does my test fail and how to fix it

You aren't using the correct syntax. This one works for me:
f(x) = 2
g(x) = x + 1
h(x) = If(f(x) > g(x), 1, 2)


